# DynamoDB Mapper For Conditional Saves With More Than One Conditions

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling, dynamodb-mapper

I have been trying to use DynamoDB mapper for creating save expressions. I want to save a record iff

1. A particular attribute value doesn't exist.
   OR
2. That attribute value should be greater than a particular value.

So I have created an expression for it, but it throws `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
expected.put("date",
                new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue()
                        .withN(Long.toString(date.toEpochMilli())))
                        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT));
        expected.put("date", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false));
        saveExpression.withConditionalOperator(ConditionalOperator.OR);
saveExpression.setExpected(expected);
```

This is the kind of exception I'm getting.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to assert the value of the fields [version], since the expected value conditions cannot be combined with user-specified conditions joined by "OR"
```

I was wondering if I'm missing something or is there something wrong??

**Edit**

Looks like I couldn't use an OR operation between two internal conditions. Is it possible to do OR-ing in some way??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if this is relevant to what your error is described.
It mentioned to `You can use SaveBehavior.CLOBBER to skip the assertion on these fields.`
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2abc7e64630cf3c6e76455af8d975ae4c452dc39/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L2223

Comment: @sham... Looks like I can't use OR between 2 internal conditions. Is there any way to use OR??